# Footer Link or Site Map

Tags: seo, sitemap, footer

I am creating a site map for a website.I have recently come to know that instead of site map I can give footer links.So I am confused whether to have a site map or footer links or both.Can anyone suggest me? (considering both Search engine optimization and users navigation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a sitemap will not damage your website. Even with a good set of footer links it's good practice to submit your sitemap to Google et al.

Considering user navigation though I must say a good footer can prove a real good tool to show users what's what and how to find it. A footer isn't a sitemap though, just a summary usually. So why not add both?

Answer (score 1):

When you submit sitemap to google - googlebot will visit your site more frequenly, and when you create new site it will index it sooner.